# How to split up form fields into different tabsheets in vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a Tabsheet with 2 tabs (A & B).  I want to put all common form fields on tab A and the specific ones on tab B.  All of the form fields make up one single entity.

For example. my data model is below (I leave out constructor.  Also this is just an example so I use only one form field).

```
public class Person extends FormLayout {
   TextField name = new TextField("Name");  //Common to all persons
}

public class Student extends Person {
   TextField grade = new TextField("Grade"); //Specific to students
}
```

I want to put Name on Tab A since it's common to all persons and Grade on Tab B since it's specific to students.  **Name and Grade made up a student**. I have a POJO called Student in the back end that will be mapped to the form fields.  I tried the below

```
tabsheet.addTab(new Person(), "Common"); //Display only Name - GOOD
tabsheet.addTab(new Student(), "Specific"); //Display both Name & Grade - BAD. I only want Grade
```

How do I split up the form fields onto different tabs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Student extends Person, so is correct the in the second tab you see both fields.

I'd consider to review the overall structure of what are you trying to accomplish.
Maybe you can try to create an helper class with two methods, one returning the common form, the other returning the specific one. Or just use one configurable instance of Student where you can mark the fields as common o specific and act accordingly in the tabs. It just doesn't seems a good design, unless I'm missing some major point ;-)

You could also use add-ons like 
https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/fieldbinder-addon
to help you out in the field handling.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question.  I need to use the BeanFieldGroup.